# Develop android app for control Samsung (H-Series) smart TV

Tags: android, samsung-smart-tv

I want to develop an android app to control Samsung smart TV (H6400). Can some one please guide me with selecting the tools and techniques for this. I just only want to control volume up/down and channel up/down features.

Answer (score 0):

I found it after digging around hours.
https://github.com/MultiScreenSDK/multiscreen-android